# SAS: do not send email when no records

Tags: sas

I'm new to SAS base and I am trying to either add a line saying all ID's transferred when nobs=0  Here's what I added on what Alex gave me which print the ID's when there are any in the data set workgo.recds_not_processed. I added nobs=0 condition but it is not sending the ID's when they are present.

```
data _null_;
   length id_list $ 3000;
   retain id_list '';
   file mymail;
   SET set workgo.recds_not_processed nobs = nobs end = eof;
   IF nobs = 0 then PUT "All ID's transferred successfully";      
   else  if _n_ = 1 then do;
      put 'Number of records not processed=' nobs;
      put 'The IDs are:';
   end;
   /* Print the IDs in chunks */
   if length(strip(id_list)) > 2000 then do;
      put id_list;
      call missing(id_list);
   end;
   call catx(', ', id_list, id);
   if eof then put id_list;
 run;
```

Comment: I imagine that's not doing anything at all, because you have mismatched do/end.

Comment: Yea, sorry about that, even if i include it it's not sending the ID's when ID's are present.

Comment: You have a line starting `SET set ` - did you mean to type just `set`?

Answer (score 1):

You are very nearly there - the unmatched `end` spotted by Joe and the double `set` that I pointed out were the only obvious errors preventing your code from working.

The reason you got no output when dealing with an empty dataset is that SAS terminates a data step when it tries to read a record from a set statement and there are none left to read. One solution is to move your empty dataset logic before the set statement.

Also, you can achieve the desired result without resorting to `retain` and `call catx` by using a double trailing `@@` in your put statement to write to the same line repeatedly from multiple observations from the input dataset:

```
data recds_not_processed;
    do id=1 to 20;
        output;
    end;
run;

data _null_;
    /*nobs is populated when the data step is compiled, so we can use it before the set statement first executes*/
    IF nobs=0 then
        do;
            PUT "All IDs transferred successfully";
            stop;
        end;
    /*We have to put the set statement after the no-records logic because SAS terminates the data step after trying to read a record when there are none remaining.*/
    SET recds_not_processed nobs=nobs end=eof;

    if _n_=1 then
        do;
            put 'Number of records not processed=' nobs;
            put 'The IDs are:';
        end;

    /* Print the IDs in chunks */
    if eof or mod(_N_, 5)=0 then
        put id;
    else
        put id +(-1) ', ' @@;
run;
```

Comment: Hi User667489 thanks for your reply but It does not print anything if the dataset is empty .. I'm not sure how to post the code that I have ,properly as a code in this comment section but here is what i have.
   <code>
     data _null_;
     set workgo.recds_not_processed nobs = nobs end = eof;
     length id_lists $ 20000;
     retain id_lists '';
     file mymail;
IF nobs=0 then
        do;
            PUT "All ID's transferred successfully";
            stop;
        end;,
</code>

Comment: Sorry, I was messing around with lots of minor variations looking for the most compact version. I've updated it now and tested with an empty dataset.

Comment: Also, removed greengrocer's apostrophe.

Comment: Thank you very much..   it worked.. I tried 
 /* Print the IDs in chunks */
    if eof or mod(_N_, 5)=0 then
        put id;
    else
        put id +(-1) ', ' @@;
run;  
The Id's are not getting printed only the commas are getting printed.. My ID is present in the workgo.recds_not_processed. there are 2 more columns in the dataset but i want only ID continuously separated with the commas

Comment: I know i'm asking too much stuff .. But you might be the best person..
I have another dataset which is workgo.id_processed. Sometimes when there are duplicates I am pulling only distinct records.. That is causing the ID's not processed email to show that duplicate as not processed.. 
Apart from checking nobs=0, can we do something like this 
proc sql;
select count(*) into :missingid from workgo.id_not_processed;
select count(*) into :itsdup from workgo.id_not_processed where id in (select id from workgo.id_processesd);
run;
if nobs=0 and &missingid.=&its_dup
PUT 'ALL ID'S TRANSFERREDT'

Comment: I suggest you have a go at coding it yourself first and then post it as a separate question if you get stuck with a specific part of it.

Comment: Will do .. thanks ..  . I tried /* Print the IDs in chunks */ if eof or mod(N, 5)=0 then put id; else put id +(-1) ', ' @@; run; The Id's are not getting printed only the commas are getting printed.. My ID is present in the workgo.recds_not_processed. there are 2 more columns in the dataset but i want only ID continuously separated with the commas